# Safe method to install Ubuntu on MBR disk with 4 primary partitions

Tags: dual-boot, 14.04, uefi, system-installation, partitioning

[image]

That's my partitions. I'm trying to dual boot Windows 8.1 and ubuntu 14.04, and I've disabled secureboot, fastboot, and all that crap. I'm trying to install it with UEFI.

What do I need to do in this box to install it? Are there too many partitions? What can I do? If you know the answer, please tell me what to do. Thanks.

Comment: Nah, I need to know if these partitions are correct, and if so, how to install it w/o ruining Windows.

Comment: The Step 8 describes it. There is another guide. Just search "Install Ubuntu Without removing Windows".

Comment: Rebooting back into Live right now. Hopefully this works.

Answer (score 0):

Those partition you have mentioned are created by windows 8.1, don't delete anything. You actual partition is sda4 (499.6GB) where windows is already installed.

For dual boot, try following the method shown [here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/tired-of-windows-8-how-to-dual-boot-windows-ubuntu/).

Comment: try the method mentioned above, but be careful not deleted those small partitions

Comment: That guide really isn't clear. It just says what to do. Do I need to do anything specific with the partitions, is 4-5 too many, or anything. It just rushes without being specific. Not really what I'm asking.

Comment: I have already mentioned , You actual partition is sda4 (499.6GB) Dont care about other ones . you actually have only one partition. Its also mentioned in that post too.  Read the manual method.